# Help with a Poisson Process problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Suppose that an average of 45 people arrive per hour to a restaurant according to a Poisson Process.

What is the probability that more than 5 minutes pass before two clients arrive to the restaurant?

I know that  = .75 per minute and that 0 or 1 client can arrive from 0 to 5 minutes.

My set up for the problem is:

$$P(N(5)<=1) = \frac{e^{-3.75}*3.75^5}{5!}$$

Is it right?

Comment: Rate for 5 min is OK. I think you are not clear about notation $N(5).$ In terms of following notation, your computation is for $P(X = 5).$ // Let $X$ be the number arriving in 5 min. Then $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_5 = 3.75)$ and you seek $P(X \le 1)$ $= P(X=0)+P(X=1) =  0.1117.$ You can use the Poisson PDF to sum the two probabilities. In R, `ppois` is a Poisson CDF, so code `ppois(1, 3.75)` returns 0.1117093.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{N(t):t\geqslant0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$, $T>0$, and $n$ a positive integer. Then
$$
\mathbb P(N(t)\leqslant n-1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}.
$$
Here $\lambda=\frac34$, $T=5$, and $n=2$, so we have
$$
\mathbb P(N(5)\leqslant 1) = e^{-\frac34\cdot5}\left(1 + \frac34\cdot 5\right)= \frac{19}4e^{-\frac{15}4}\approx0.1117093.
$$